# WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response... throws org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException, should not consume any entity

Tags: java, web-services, rest, api, get

I have the following GET method, and it fails to send send back the result to the client.

```
/*@GET here defines, this method will process HTTP GET requests. */
@GET
@Path("/test/{name}/{status}")
@Produces("application/json")
  public Response Name(@PathParam("name,status") String name, String status ) throws JSONException {
  String total = "100";
  .
  .
  .
  String result = "" + jsonObject;

  return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
```

When I run it, I have the message below:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response... throws org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException, should not consume any entity.

Does it have to do with the fact that I have two parameters ?

I already checked online but nothing relevant to my situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I think I have found the issue...it should be like this: Name(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("status") String status ) Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I think I have found the issue...it should be like this:

```
Name(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("status") String status )
```

Thanks!

Comment: In our case we were using a single Pojo bean so adding @BeanParam in front of the parameter solved the issue as well...

Comment: This answer could be improved by actually explaining what the change was, rather than leaving it to the reader to mentally diff this code snippet with the one in the question and guessing what the fix was.